# how to prompt the user for the integer input to the function, and return it as string message?

Tags: python, function

I am a beginner to Python and I have the following test question. Write a Python program that defines a function called `myDate`. Tprogram must prompt the user for the input to the function, namely are three integers (`nDay`, `nMonth`, `nYear`). The output from the function must be a string message describing your birthday. 
For example:

```
You were born on 10 october 1995.
```

The function call the `theMessage = myDate(nDay, nMonth, nYear)`, must be followed by a `print(theMessage)`.

I tried it as follows:

```
def myDate(nDay, nMonth, nYear):
...     if nMonth == 1:
...         return "January"
...     if nMonth == 2:
...         return "February"
...     if nMonth == 3:
...         return "March"
...     if nMonth == 4:
...         return "April"
...     if nMonth == 5:
...         return "May"
...     if nMonth == 6:
...         return "June"
...     if nMonth == 7:
...         return "July"
...     if nMonth == 8:
...         return "August"
...     if nMonth == 9:
...         return "September"
...     if nMonth == 10:
...         return "October"
...     if nMonth == 11:
...         return "November"
...     if nMonth == 12:
...         return "December"
...     
nDay = int(input("Day"))
Day>? 25

nMonth = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 12: "))
Enter a number between 1 and 12: >? 10

nYear = int(input("Year"))
Year>? 1998

theMessage = myDate(nDay, nMonth, nYear)

print(theMessage)

output: October
```

I would like to get help on how to get the whole message instead of the month only.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, try using this as your message `theMessage = f"You were born on {nDay} {myDate(nDay, nMonth, nYear)} {nYear}"` and then print it.

Answer (score 0):

I will change the code like this:

```
import datetime
def myDate(nDay,nMonth,nYear):
  theDate = datetime.date(nYear, nMonth, nDay).strftime('You were born on %d %B %Y')
  return theDate

nDay = int(input("Day"))
nMonth = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 12: "))
nYear = int(input("Year"))
theMessage = myDate(nDay, nMonth, nYear)
print(theMessage)
```